# Is there a way to return a type that is one item in an array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to define a typescript function that accepts an array of strings and then returns a string. The string is guaranteed to be one of the options in the array. I want the return type to be `"string1" | "string2" | "string3"` rather than just a generic `string`.

This way the person who calls the function can use typescript on the returned value.

Comment: How have you tried to solve this (show the code) and can you explain what doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

From the problem definition it looks like you are trying to convert the `array/tuple` of strings into `union-type`. One of the ways is to use the [`as const`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to achieve this which is available from `version 3.4`. Below is the sample code -

```
const array = ['x', 'y', 'z'] as const; 
type UnionType = typeof array[number]; // type "x" | "y" | "z"

const func = (input: typeof array): UnionType => {
  return 'x';
};

console.log(func(['x', 'y', 'z']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a union type: `type myType =  "string1" | "string2" | "string3";`
That should do it